# out of topic discussion on others answer

Tags: discussion, comments

Here is unappropriate comment on others answer:

Can we remove it?

[Can't checkout when remove country field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244227/cant-checkout-when-remove-country-field/244230?noredirect=1#comment341611_244230)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Flag those comments and give specific reason, which you found unappropriate. It will be removed by Moderator if your reason is valid.

Comment: Thank you   Piyush

Answer (score 2):

**METHOD 1 :**

1. Select that comment for flag
2. Select Something else option and explain the issue what you want to tell to moderators.
3. Then sure they will take action

Otherwise, Do the following :

**METHOD 2 :**

Add your comment to the user who was posted irrelated to the content to remove the comment or ask at correct place. If they removed its fine. Or else You can go with moderator.

[image]